# Android get image from server to SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mobile, bitmap

Android get image from server to SQLite database

I need to display images in the news section and when there is no internet connection i want to read them offline. I did it with the title and the body text but for the news image it is too slow how can I improve that?

I tried to get the string url and store it as byte array:

```
         public byte[] downloadImage(String urlImg) throws Exception{

            URL url = new URL(urlImg);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setReadTimeout(10000);
            con.setConnectTimeout(10000);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            try {
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(con.getInputStream());
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 0, bos);
            } finally {
                con.disconnect();
            }

            return bos.toByteArray();
        }
```

then I call it inside the doInBackground like this:

```
@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://www.77-webdev.com/clients/thebeautyworkshop/news.json");
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (status == 200){
                    DataSource.deleteAll();
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("News");
                    News news = new News();
                    for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject JObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String Title =  JObject.getString("title");
                        String body =  JObject.getString("mobile_body");
                        String Image =  JObject.getString("image");
                        String lang =  JObject.getString("lang");
                        byte[]  IMG = downloadImage(Image);


                        news.setTitle(Title);
                        news.setMobile_body(body);
                        news.setImageB(IMG);
                        news.setLang(lang);
                        DataSource.create(news);
                        newsList.add(news);

                    }

                    return true;
                }


            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

but it's too because I'm connecting for each image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know into which view you want to put the image, you can use [Square's Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to simplify the image process:

```
Picasso
        .with(context)
        .load(Image)
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: but if I open the application without internet connection it's not going to load the images

Comment: If you've opened the application previously, the images will be cached on the device. If not, then you need to go a completely different route than both your code and my example.

Comment: I ended up using Universal Image Loader but ur answer guided me to fix the problem